# MS Excel on MAC - need to use values from a dependent data validation list and populate in respective sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Background: I am using Excel on Mac, and I have found that there is no support for forms on Excel for Mac.

What I am trying to do: I need to create something similar to a form in Excel for Mac and use the input data into respective Excel sheets corresponding to the data entered.

Here is a sample form:

[image]

In the screenshot, the fields `TG` and `Subtechnology` are dependent lists. If I choose a different value for `TG`, then the drop down options for `Sub Technology` will change.

When the user fills the three fields - C12, C14, and C16, the values captured here will go and sit in a sheet (let's call this sheet EN_WL, previously created) respective to the selection in C10- in this case - Wireless.

In EN_WL I have a formula that copies the values in C12, 14, and 16. I am using a simple IF statement for doing this copy.

```
=IF('Input Form'!C10="Wireless",'Input Form'!C12, "")
```

Problem: It is fine thus far, I can choose the subtech as Wireless and the user-entered values in C12,14 & 16 are captured fine in the "EN_WL" Sheet, BUT if I were to enter another value under Subtech, let's call it "Wired".. (Corresponding sheet for Wired would be EN_WD) the values in C12, 14 and 16 copy over to En_WD, but they get deleted in EN_WL. However, I need the previously entered values in C12, 14 & 16 for Wireless-Sub technology to remain in the EN_WL sheet. and the new values to go over to the EN_WD sheet.

Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.